# C# parsing html with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing

I need to parse html code after executing javascript code inside this document.
I use webBrowser control for downloading and controling html.

For example, I have some javascript in my html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/script.js"></script>
```

Thank for your answers.

P.S.
I mean: I must parse all code with some text wich can return javascript. So, I can parse document only after execution javascript. Becouse I need some part of dinamic content wich will be added with javascript.

**Added**

I got content with javascript generated content. I skipped this one, because I was looking for some content that was in iframe which was generated with javascript.

And now I have another question. In my document I have few iframes. I am trying to get content from some frames. In the next way:

```
        var htmlcol = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames;
        foreach (HtmlWindow item in htmlcol)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write(item.Name);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something wrong");
            }

        }
```

But in this way I have exception: '**System.UnauthorizedAccessException**'. How I can get access to html of frames?

P.P.S. Sory for my bad english :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about this?

Comment: What are you actually asking everyone to help you do? Reading the html? Parsing the <script> tags? Parse during some javascript call?

Comment: I mean: I must parse all code with some text wich can return javascript. So, I can parse document only after execution javascript. Becouse I need some part of dinamic content wich will be added with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will have a better experience using the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp) as represented using the [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property of the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx).

You can either traverse the nested elements of [`Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body.aspx), or find what you want using [`GetElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) or [`GetElementsByTagName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx).

The DOM should be automatically updated by the changes the JavaScript makes in the page.

Comment: Thank. It works. Maybe and has been worked before. I skipped this Because, I was looking for some content which was showed in iframe. Which was generated in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
- Add reference Microsoft.mshtml to your application.

Try:

```
public void setPage(mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class JSFile)
{
HTMLWindow2Class window = new HTMLWindow2Class();
window = JSFile;

}
public void scriptPrint()
{
IHTMLDocument2 doc = null; ;
IHTMLWindow2 parentwindow = doc.parentWindow;



parentwindow.execScript("report_back('Printing complete!')", "JScript");
}

}
```

Here's also an article that might help you:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=194

Comment: How would he execute the JavaScript though?

Answer (score 0):

Please read Phantomjs for your issue and use setTimeOut for page open.

This can loke like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        // Execution somethings before page load. for Example: 
        localStorage.setItem("something", "whatever");// Set LocalStorage for browser before open
    });

    page.open("https://sample.com", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(page.content); //page source

            // Where you want to save it    
            page.render("screenshoot.png")  

            // You can access its content using jQuery
            var fbcomments = page.evaluate(function(){
                return $("body").contents().find(".content") 
            }) 

            phantom.exit();
        },10000)
    });    
});
```